# How to disable WARN when connecting to SQL database in Java

Tags: java, mysql, ssl

In a Java application I'm programming, when I ask the program to retrieve data from an SQL database, it shows this in console :

`Wed Apr 20 16:57:58 MDT 2016 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.`

I know that's a lot to read, and I have SSL disabled in the SQL workbench, so I can't figure out how to get rid of the warning or if I should even be concerned about it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do what it says and add `useSSL=false` to the connection string.

Comment: Yupp just figured that out... Thanks though. \[+]/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try to use the useSSL=false in the connection string

Example:

> jdbc:mysql://xxxxxxx:3306/xxxx?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false

EDIT:

I had issue today 11/20/2019 while connecting mysql version 8.0.12 using java mysql driver (com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver, 8.0.18) and got following error

Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Public Key Retrieval is not allowed

I had to add `allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true` to connection string to fix the connection issue.

Updated this answer because its related issue :)

Comment: @EthanMoore why would you delete it?

Comment: @EthanMoore just because you figured out the right answer doesn't mean you should delete it, it can come in handy for someone else. Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

**Replace** – jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo

**With** – jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo?useSSL=false

Answer (score 1):

In case someone uses **MysqlDataSource**, which is preferred over DriverManager you can you the `setUseSSL(boolean sslstate)` function :

```
MysqlDataSource dataSource = new MysqlDataSource();
dataSource.setUser("USER_NAME");
dataSource.setPassword("PASSWORK");
dataSource.setServerName("localhost"); //most likely
dataSource.setDatabaseName("DATABASE_NAME");
dataSource.setUseSSL(false); //Disable SSL
try(
    Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection();
)
{
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME ...");
} catch (SQLException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```